# Split a list of data.frames into sublists of data.frames

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames that looks like:

```
List          
[[1]]                
    .....               
  List             
   [[2]]            
  ....           

 List              
[[95]]
```

I would like to split this long list of data.frames in sublists of 3 data.frames each in order to do other computations in a simple and easy way.

Something like:

> sublist1 <- List[1:3]
>      sublist2 <- List[3:6]
>      sublist3 <- List[6:9]

and so on.

Comment: What do you mean you would like to "split" the list? Do you mean assign subsets of the list to new objects in your workspace? Why not just run your calculations on the subsets directly?

Comment: Hi Ananda! Yes, I would like to assign subsets of the list to new objects. It's to run calculations and to visualize the output easiest, too.

Comment: @Fuv8 Have you considered placing all these subsets as elements in a list? I try to avoid cluttering my workspace if possible.

Comment: No, not considered, but it is a good idea. Thank you for this suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
ll <- by(seq_along(l),cut(seq_along(l),3),
                 FUN=function(x)l[x])
```

Now I have , a list which contains 3 lists. For example to access first sub-lists, you can do :

```
ll[[1]]
[[1]]
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

[[2]]
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

[[3]]
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

And so on , ll[[2]]...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `assign` and do something like this:

```
d <- data.frame()
l <- list(d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d)

for(i in seq(1, length(l), by=3)) {
    assign(paste0("x", i), l[i:(i+2)])
}

> ls()
# [1] "d"  "i"  "l"  "x1" "x4" "x7"
```

Comment: @Fuv8, Sure! Although I've to say it is better to deal with `list-of-lists` instead of assigning each of these lists to a separate variable (as sebastian-c suggests and agstudy provides solution for).